# Is it possible to ignore duplicate errors at spring data with MongoRepository saveAll function?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

Is it possible to ignore duplicate errors at spring data with MongoRepository saveAll function? i have a two concurrent writers to mongodb and they are saving same content and i want to be safe, that while saving on both sides with saveall works well (one can be have a duplication error) and not both of them throws duplication error on same time and nothing will be saved in db.

concurrent saving only one must win to save list with saveall